# Socket.Receive blocking even after ShutDown() by client

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a server application with a socket listening:

```
server = new TcpListener(myEndPoint);

// etc.

socket = server.AcceptSocket();

while (true) {

    int size = socket.Receive(data); // application waits here for data.

    if (size == 0)
    {
        // handle disconnect
    }
    else
    {
        // process data.
    }
}
```

Now the client application connects to this...

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.Connect(remoteIp, remotePort);
```

sends the data, and when it's done it calls

```
socket.ShutDown(SocketShutdown.Both);
```

At this point, I'd expect the server, which was blocking at `socket.Receive(data)` to proceed, but with a `size` of 0.

as per this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.7.2

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

But it just waits here forever.

The funny thing is, if I connect to the server application with PuTTY, and then close PuTTY, then the `Receive()` method *does* complete and return with `size` = 0. What's PuTTY doing that I'm not?

Note: I've also tried using a `TcpClient` on the client application but this has the same problem.

Comment: socket.ShutDown disables Send/Receive on the socket. Can you try socket.Close() to close the connection.

Comment: @Minu - Actually I've just noticed that it works fine if I don't send any data and then either Close() or Shutdown(). However if I do send data and call either, then Receive() continues blocking. I can see from the debugger that the `Available` property of the socket is 7 if I've sent data but 0 if not...

Comment: Ahh figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my fault, I'll leave it here in case someone else has the same problem.

While trying Minu's suggestion I noticed that if I just closed the socket without having sent data, the `Receive()` completed correctly.

It turns out that elsewhere in my code, I had the server sending back an acknowledgement after receiving the completed data. However, the client's method to receive the acknowledgement had a bug in it that was causing it not to completely receive it from the socket and so there were still 7 bytes `Available` on the socket which is why it wasn't closing.